# Unable upgrade rails from 5.0.6 to 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, resque

I'm using ruby 2.4.2 and rails 5.0.6(system running well), and I'm trying to upgrade to rails 5.1.4, I changed Gemfiles from from gem 'rails', '5.0.6' to gem 'rails', '5.1.4', and run bundle update,

my question is when I did bundle update, **Why** redis-namespace downgraded to version 0.4.3 and resque downgraded to version 1.8.2 see trace console below.

```
Using redis 4.0.1 (was 3.3.5)
Using redis-namespace 0.4.3 (was 1.5.3)
Using resque 1.8.2 (was 1.27.4)
```

this causing I cannot run rails server, Thank you.

#### edit 2

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.19'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
# gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1' # please note 4.2.1 is the compatible one
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc
gem 'rake'
gem 'bootstrap-sass' # for twitter bootstrap
gem 'material_icons' # icon
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'rmagick', require: false
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table'
# resque
gem 'resque'
gem "sinatra", ">= 2.0.0.beta2", require: false 
gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
# csv import
gem 'smarter_csv'

# redis action cable
gem "hiredis"
gem "redis"

# webserver
gem 'puma', '3.6.2'
```

#### edit 3

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis":
  In Gemfile:
    redis (>= 4.0.1)

    resque (~> 1.27.0) was resolved to 1.27.4, which depends on
      redis-namespace (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
        redis (~> 3.0.0)
```

Comment: could you post yr gemfile ?

Comment: sure, I just updated

Comment: can you try just specifying exactly version `gem 'redis', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'` and so on https://rubygems.org/gems/redis

Comment: I just did your info, and I get another error (see edit 3)

Comment: try `bundle update` also because lock.file blocks | and include other gems that u have mention from rubygems.org

Comment: @7urkm3n thank you,  from your guide above, and an error message, I think I found my problem, I have to use gem "redis-rails" , It seems working and I can run rails server but need to check resque (still researching now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After did another researched and another error message I just found that for rails 5.x should use redis-rails instead of redis and another issue that I found today also json (needed by resque gem and sdoc), make sure gem 'json' with version >= 2.1.0 listed in Gemfile, if not usually bundler will install version 1.8.6 (which generate an error with rails 5.x), so for I found these 2 errors, I will update my answer in case I found another

Gemfile

```
gem "redis-rails"
gem 'json', '>= 2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with fixing gem dependencies to a patch/minor version.

You should try using `gem redis` only in your Gemfile and then run `bundle update`. This should fix the issue. Some tests may break though especially if the public api of redis has been updated since the older version of redis. You may need to find the newer API to have everything working normally.